# How do I clean the bottom of a gas grill?

Tags: cleaning, food, food-safety

> **What is the best way to clean the bottom of a gas grill?**

Wire brushes apparently work for the grilling surface. The metal grid that touches the food. But when that is cleaned, the gunk falls into the pan below. Along with all the other burnt grease, food juice and other cooking residue?

What's the best way to clean that out?

Comment: Aren't this described in the user manual? Why doesn't that guide work? What kind of a gas grill is it, can you remove the "pack with the gunk"?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of cleaning that area?  Is it catching fire?  Are you cooking off that area?  Are you OCD?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom of most gas grills is a removable tray. It's easiest to remove it, use a 3-inch wide putty knife to scrape most of the crud off, and then use oven cleaner to remove the rest.

It can still be done with some non-removable bottoms, it just takes longer to work around the burners.

Answer (score 1):

If that area is already gunked up, get out your long rubber gloves and some oven cleaner. And a gas mask. **Unhook the tank before you do any of this.** If you have a complete nightmare to deal with you can remove the burners. Most grills have fairly simple connections that allow you to remove the burners. So remove the burners and anything else not connected to the grill body and get strong cleaners and a hose. Lots of cleaner and lots of rinsing will get you there.

A little preventative work goes a long way - line the bottom of the grill and any pans in foil before you put food on it.

Answer (score 1):

spray it down with some generic degreaser, or soapy water.  spray it with the hose.  Be sure to get in all the crevices.  It will leave gunk under the grill, but you don't have to get dirty or scrub.